# How to create domain entity object from entityForm?

Tags: spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

In Broadleaf Commerce framework, I am looking for a way to pull domain entity objects like **product**, **admin user** from entity form that we receice as model attribute in CRUD methods of EntityController classes like **AdminProductController**. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Below is a sample code from AdminProductController class.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEntity(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,
                @PathVariable  Map<String, String> pathVars,
                @ModelAttribute(value="entityForm") EntityForm entityForm, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
    //some code
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to explain a little more about what you're trying to accomplish (no implementation details), so we can help. Try to use the same terms that are in the Spring docs

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan basically it is related to Broadleaf Commerce(BLC). In BLC whenever we want to update data(of product, user, category) from admin module all the fields of a table is wrapped in form of entityForm which is again used to store data in database. Now I would like to know if there is a way to pull out actual entity object from entityform? Here entity object means object of Product, User, Category, etc.

Comment: Can you not use actual entity type in your method signature instead of the form type? Or consider Dozer to easily copy between types